# What is the origin of the Collatz conjecture?

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

When was the $3x+1$ problem first proposed?

At [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), I found the following statement (without citation):

> The Collatz conjecture is a conjecture in mathematics named after Lothar Collatz, who first proposed it in 1937.

There is the following article

- Lothar Collatz, *On the Motivation and Origin of the ($3n+1$)-Problem*.

which is very short and was translated into Chinese and  published there. By the way, why would a German mathematician translate an article to Chinese and publish it there and not in Germany? A translation to English can be found in the book *The Ultimate Challenge: The $3x+1$ Problem*.

In the article, Collatz claims that he discovered the problem, and mentions three years:

> Through the lectures of [...] from 1928 through 1933, I became in interested in problems in the areas of number theoretic functions and graph theory.

and

> I have experimented with many numbers. Before 1950 computers were not as well-developed as they are today. Therefore I could not try any large numbers.

Thus, it sounds to me that the problem must have arisen between 1928-1950. But how does Wikipedia know its from the year 1937?

Comment: According to the fairly authoritative https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Lagarias3-23.pdf (at least I think so!), there is no definite birth year of the problem, but Collatz was looking at similar problems in the early 1930s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wikipedia does not actually know that it is from 1937, my guess is that they picked a number between 1929 and 1950. According to Lagarias, who compiled an [exhaustive bibliography](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309224.pdf) on the problem, the first publication only appears in 1963, and is by Klamkin, he also gives other names it acquired: Syracuse Problem, Hasse’s Algorithm, Kakutani’s Problem and Ulam’s Problem. Early history is addressed more specifically in his [American Mathematical Monthly article](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/lagarias/paper/html/node1.html), which cites first hand accounts (and links to some of them) that are not publications. Thwaites, who calls it Ulam's problem, recalled that he stated the $3x+1$ problem already back in 1952. Hasse promoted the problem during his visit to the Syracuse university in 1950s, Kakutani got involved around 1960:*"For about a month everybody at Yale worked on it, with no result. A similar phenomenon happened when I mentioned it at the University of Chicago. A joke was made that this problem was part of a conspiracy to slow down mathematical research in the U.S.*"

Collatz himself circulated similar iteration problems at the International Congress of Mathematicians in 1950, although it is unclear if $3x+1$ specifically was among them. One such iterative function already appears in his notebook entry from July 1, 1932. Collatz wrote several letters in 1976-1980, where he reminisced about those early days, but as Lagarias points out "*in none of these letters does L. Collatz actually state that he proposed the $3x+1$ problem*".

He implies it though in a letter to Mays written in 1980 and [translated here](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/lagarias/paper/goodies/ubersetzung/html/ubersetzung.html), and explains his motivation for studying such functions:"*In 1929 I attended classes of E. Land and lectures in number theory given by Lettenmeyer, both in Göttingen, and in 1930 I attended classes given by O. Perron in Munich and Isai Schur in Berlin. I found it interesting to sketch the graphs of number theoretic functions $f(n)$ by drawing an arrow from $n$ to $f(n)$, or more simply, by writing $f(n)$ under $n$. (In this way) one can find various concepts which are well known in the theory of digraphs such as trees, cycles, bifurcation, etc. I don't know who the first person was to make these connections to graph theory; I, however, have seen neither in lectures nor in published form this type of representation of number theoretic functions. I enjoy observing the various patterns, and I computed the graphs (at the time of these investigations) of many interesting number theoretic functions for values of $n$ up to about $100$. I examined the example that I mention above* [the conventional $3n+1$] *in this way too...*" This is as first hand and definitive as it gets without a contemporary document, and there is no 1937 in it.